# How to get a feed for post type 'page'?

Tags: pages, rss, feed

I'm trying to get a feed for pages and a separate feed for posts. The feed for posts works perfect as it is.

I just want a separate one but i have tried all the plugins and searched for about a week straight and still could not find a solution

Is it possible to take feed-rss2.php and duplicate it to change the code to include pages instead of posts and call it by `?feed=my_custom_feed`?

EDIT BELOW:

http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/qWdqc/

This is the script that I am using get the `<link>` tag from the item RSS. I want the pages to have an RSS feed unless anyone knows a different way of doing it without RSS. But the script above rotates the page every 30 seconds.

Comment: Feeds don't report content updates, they report *new* content.  So new posts are added to a feed as new items ... what are you trying to accomplish with a feed for pages? There's probably a better way to go about it.

Comment: please view the topic for update ....

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking at that code and I still haven't a clue what you're trying to do. Could you perhaps explain your goal using English instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Feeds for post types are called with `feed/?post_type=POSTTYPE`. For no obvious reasons this doesn't work for the post type `page` – you get the posts instead.

But there is a filter to fix that: `'pre_get_posts'`. Let's use it:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 't5_pages_in_feed' );

/**
 * Set post type to 'page' if it was requested.
 *
 * @param  object $query
 * @return void
 */
function t5_pages_in_feed( &$query )
{
    if ( isset ( $_GET['post_type'] ) && $_GET['post_type'] === 'page' && is_feed() )
    {
        $query->set( 'post_type', 'page' );
    }
}
```

Now you get the page feed at `/feed/?post_type=page`.

Here is a plugin for that: [T5 Page Feed](https://gist.github.com/2765738)

Comment: sorry im a bit of a wordpress/web newbie where would i put this ? in functions.php or feed-rss2.php ?

Comment: `functions.php` or better: a plugin. See my update.

Comment: ERROR: rss2 is not a valid feed template. <-- this is the error that i get when i try to use it http://directitpros.com/cbm/wp/feed/?post_type=page

Comment: That's from `wp-includes/functions.php:do_feed()`. Meaning: you have feeds disabled or some other strange filter is active. Disable all plugins and Use TwentyEleven. Do you still get the error?

Comment: AWESOME AWESOME works great thanks so much works great

Comment: Question how can i update the feed seems to keep the deleted page in there for some time

Comment: That's a [separate question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). May be a browser caching issue, check that first.

Comment: I tired on a few different computers anyway to refresh the feed?

Comment: Works on my machine. Probably a caching plugin. _Ask a new question for that_.