# Remove specific page/post from feed

Tags: pages, rss, feed, customization

I'm working on a website with lots of tutorials/pages.

I have made a [separate rss feed](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/52853/how-to-get-a-feed-for-post-type-page) for the pages - works fine.
But then I had to create a sitemap (a page), and it shows up in my "pages" rss feed!

**My Question:** How can I remove a specific post/page from a feed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick and dirty way is set the published date a year or so in the past, past the oldest posts in the feed.  There's also a nice plugin for this - [Stealth Publish](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/stealth-publish/) - where you set a flag in a custom field to exclude it from feeds and the home page feed.

Comment: XD never thought of that!! :D

Comment: I learned it by accident a few years ago - amazing how many things I've learned like that, actually.

Answer (score 0):

A simple custom solution is also possible and you have not the overflow of this plugin, the ui and so on.

```
function fb_exclude_filter($query) {
    if ( !$query->is_admin && $query->is_feed) {
        $query->set('post__not_in', array(40, 9) ); // id of page or post
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'fb_exclude_filter' );
```

for more background information [see my post](http://wpengineer.com/2175/exclude-post-from-wordpress-feed/)