# How can I add certain pages (not posts) to my sites RSS feed?

Tags: rss

How can I add specific pages content to my sites RSS feed? As of right now the RSS feed automatically displays all of the sites posts content, but I want to add the RSS functionality to certain pages as well. Is there any way of doing this? Thank you.

Comment: RSS isn’t really for static content. It’s intended for a feed of updating content. Why do you need to add pages to it?

Answer (score 0):

This is tested and works but you may get unexpected results.

```
function wpse_rss_pages($qv){
    $rss_feed = array('post', 'page');
    if(isset($qv['feed']) && !isset($qv['post_type']))
        $qv['post_type'] = $rss_feed;
    return $qv;
}

add_filter('request', 'wpse_rss_pages');
```

You could also seperate the feed by doing something like [THIS](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/52855/86845).